# Return Child Object with LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I'm learning many-to-many joint tables within EF Core and LINQ. I have the following model:

```
    public class ProjectManager
    {
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public Project Project { get; set; }

        public string AppUserID { get; set; }
        public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
    }
```

I have the following ViewModel:

```
    public class DeleteUserFromProjectViewModel
    {
        public IQueryable<AppUser> Users { get; set; }
        public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

In my controller, I try to populate the `Users` for my ViewModel:

```
                DeleteUserFromProjectViewModel model = new DeleteUserFromProjectViewModel
                {
                    //HOW DO I RETURN JUST THE APPUSERS FROM THE PROJECT MANAGER OBJECT?
                    //Users = repository.ProjectManagers.Any(p => p.ProjectID == projectId).Select;

                    PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                    {
                        CurrentPage = page,
                        ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                        TotalItems = proj.ProjectManagers.Count()
                    }

                };
```

I've tried the kludge

```
                List<AppUser> userList = new List<AppUser>();
                foreach(ProjectManager pm in proj.ProjectManagers)
                {
                    //this gives error that cannot convert string userId to char??
                    foreach (string userId in pm.AppUserID)
                    {
                        AppUser newUser = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
                        userList.Add(newUser);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of your `pm.AppUserID` already is a string value, if you use `foreach` on it you will iterator string value then you will get `char`

From your comment, you seem like can use linq `Select`.

```
List<AppUser> userList = proj.ProjectManagers.Select(x=>x.AppUser).ToList();
```

Comment: I think that must be close, but I'm getting the error `Cannot implicitly convert the type System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<AppUser>> to System.Linq.IQueryable<AppUser>`

Comment: I haven't gotten `FindByIdAsync` to work yet with my `ProjectManager` class. Is it possible to do a `repository.ProjectManagers.Where(...)` call? I already have my dbContext set up with the `Projectmanagers` data

Comment: or you can try my edit answer  use `repository.ProjectManagers.Select(x=>x.AppUser).ToList()`

Comment: No problem glad to help